# Brightness filter in firefox and opera without svg file

Tags: css, image, html, svg-filters

For my current project i used filter    `-webkit-filter: brightness(-20%);-moz-filter: brightness(-20%);`     But somewhy, this filter doesnt works in firefox and opera(i have opera prefix too). I found, the way how this can be used, but i need to turn brightness filter into svg code. Any ideas how can i do this?
What i have to do, is a small gallery, with darkened images, and with normal images on hover without using 2x images.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You want to use an SVG filter. An example of a filter that will darken your image by a fixed amount in each channel is:

```
<filter id="darken">
<feComponentTransfer>
       <feFuncR type="linear" intercept="-0.2" slope="1"/>
       <feFuncG type="linear" intercept="-0.2" slope="1"/>
       <feFuncB type="linear" intercept="-0.2" slope="1"/>
   </feComponentTransfer>
</filter>
```

This will darken your image by 20% in each color channel. [Full jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/T3pb8/28/)

Comment: In the MDN page about css filters, there are some svg fallback examples. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/filter

Answer (score 4):

If you need a more cross-browser solution, you could make the images translucent when they are not hovered:

```
img {
    opacity: .7;
}
img:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

This will have the effect of darkening them when they are on a dark background.