# Dark background opacity on hover

Tags: css, hover

I have this CSS. When you hover the image background turns a white opacity, but I'd like it to turn a dark opacity. I tried adding a dark background color but nothing.

```
.img-container .img-item a.image:hover img {
   opacity: .2;
   filter: alpha(opacity=50);
   background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
   transition: all 1s;
   -webkit-transition: all 1s;
    }
```

Comment: Maybe this help someone, darken an image https://stackoverflow.com/a/15765969/4573839

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Put your img in a div with bg color dark and opacity 0.5
And give z-index for the div a bigger value than for img.

```
#imgcontainer
{
opacity:0.5;
background-color: Black;
z-index:10;
}
#imgcontainer img
{
      Z-index: 5;
}
```

Comment: I did that. it's good, but the images are all different widths and heights and responsive so they get large as you resize the browser but then the container div on hover it creates bars http://screencast.com/t/GzN1owzT9 is there a workaround?

Comment: I solved this problem  by adding a max-width to the container so it stays the same width of the image on resize of browser. Worked. Accepted answer. Awesome!

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle for future references?

Answer (score 0):

you can't add background to an image, instead, you can add `background-color` at parent element.