# Darken png image

Tags: css

I have an png image that is triangle shaped , i need this image to be more dark , i get the job done using another div with opacity 0.5 that covers it e.g

```
<div class ="cover_photo">
  <div class ="overlay"></div>
</div>

  .overlay {
    background-color: #322D36 ;
     bottom: 0;
     left: 0;
     opacity: 0.5;
     position: absolute;
     right: 0;
     top: 0;
     z-index: 1;
}
```

the cover_photo has said img set as background , but using this , the color from overlay will be seen on whole div , not just on the image and thas not what i want. Is there a way how to darken an image? I know about filter css property but none of them actually darken the image. Is tehre any way to achieve it?

Comment: The `filter` property doesn't work in all browsers. Did you try using `-webkit-filter: brightness(0.5)`?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15765550/darkening-an-image-with-css-in-any-shape

Comment: filter, opacity, mix-blend-mode, filter + svg , ... many method could be used, but we have no idea of color and opacity of your png, nor the css , design in action around it you get guesses as answers :)

Comment: @AustinKilduff Is it possible to use brigthness only one of the background images? I am using two right now but want the brightness only affect the first one.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

```
.red-triangle {
  border-left: 50px solid transparent;
  border-right: 50px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 100px solid red;
}
```

This is basically setting the bottom border to be really fat, then trims off the sides with transparent `border-left` and `border-right` props.  You could presumably also add border-radius properties to get rounded corners, but I haven't tried this.

It might just be easier to use a bitmap editor or something to darken it.  Alternatively, if you're looking to do dynamic (or automated) processing, check out [imagemagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php)

Answer (score 0):

You could just apply a `linear-gradient` to the image. Since you don't actually want a gradient, just set both values of the gradient equal. Here is an example of what I am talking about:

```
background:
    /* gradient */ 
    linear-gradient(
      rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7), 
      rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7)
    ),
    /* image */
    url('Add a URL here');
}
```

Comment: this will add gradient to whole space in div , not just on image