# Changing brightness filter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to use jQuery to change the brightness filter css property of some of the images on my page, but I get the following error in the console: "Error in parsing value for 'filter'. Declaration dropped."

Here is the code I am using:

```
function changeBrightness() {
     $("#myImg").css({
     "filter"         : "brightness(50%)",
     "-webkit-filter" : "brightness(50%)",
     "-moz-filter"    : "brightness(50%)",
     "-o-filter"      : "brightness(50%)",
     "-ms-filter"     : "brightness(50%)"
     });
}
```

I also tried other formats of the above, just to see if it would work, but they produce the same error:

```
function changeBrightness() {
     var brightness = "brightness(50%)";
     $("#myImg")
        .css("filter",brightness)
        .css("webkitFilter",brightness)
        .css("mozFilter",brightness)
        .css("oFilter",brightness)
        .css("msFilter",brightness);
}
```

And I tried this general format as well, hoping jQuery would take care of the prefixes:

```
function changeBrightness() {
     $("#myImg").css("filter", "brightness(50%)");
}
```

The changeBrightness function is called when I click a button, and it should change the brightness of an image with the id "myImg" to 50%. I am using Firefox 24.7. Is the filter property for CSS3 just not functional in firefox (or any other browsers)?

Comment: According to MDN, `Gecko currently only implements the url() form of the filter property`. This might be useful: [Brightness Filter in Firefox and Opera without SVG File](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11325732/brightness-filter-in-firefox-and-opera-without-svg-file)

Comment: Here's an [example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/T3pb8/157/) based on [Michael Mullany's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11325732/brightness-filter-in-firefox-and-opera-without-svg-file#answer-12810906).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is the filter property for CSS3 just not functional in firefox (or any other browsers)?

[Here is the answer from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter):

> **This is an experimental technology**
>
> Because this technology's specification has not stabilized, check the [compatibility table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter#Browser_compatibility) for the proper prefixes to use in various browsers. Also note that the syntax and behavior of an experimental technology is subject to change in future versions of browsers as the spec changes.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Firefox doesn't globally support it.

Check out [caniuse.com/#search=filter](http://caniuse.com/#search=filter).

Btw, [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com) is a great resource for checking this kind of stuff.

Comment: But Firefox does have partial support for the `url()` form of `filter`.

Comment: @showdev The partial support is slightly misleading, considering `url()` is only for Firefox 31