# Fade effect without transparency in css

Tags: css, colors, less

I would like to fade some object without making them transparent.

Something like the [lighten](http://lesscss.org/functions/#color-operations-lighten) function of less.

Is it possible with CSS?

Comment: Given that [tag:less] compiles - to the best of my knowledge - to plain CSS, then yes, f course it is. Where did you get stuck when you tried?

Comment: I can't use less because some styles are inline

Comment: I found a solution here by using SVG: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12810906/272839